ggplotly produces a blank plot
I have having significant difficulty with plotly in R.  The code below produces a blank plot, even though calling 'p' without the ggplotly produces a plot.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled both R and RStudio but the problem persists.
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point()

ggplotly(p)

I have tried several possible fixes.  R, RStudio, and plotly are all the latest versions: R 4.4.0, RStudio 2024.04.1, plotly 4.10.4.
The code below will produce a plot on a separate page in the web browser:
plot <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(plot, "test_plot.html")
browseURL("test_plot.html")


can you send a screen shot of your script and blank plot?
I've run your code and can't reproduce your error

Thank you very much for looking into it.

I can't seem to put a screenshot in here, but the 'Viewer' pane is completely white.

This is a known issue with the R Studio Viewer that affects all htmlwidget-based libraries, not just plotly. It has to do with R 4.4.0. You can either downgrade to R 4.3.3 or download a patched version of R 4.4.0 and that should resolve the issue.

@ErikJensen Welcome to SO! You can paste a screenshot directly into the SO text. I had the same issue before I downloaded the above patch.

Amazing!  It works now.  Thank you very much @cristian-vargas.  You saved the day!

Simply do this:


library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

plot <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(plot, "test_plot.html")
browseURL("test_plot.html")


which returns

